# Need recommendations for Image Editing Library

Tags: wpf, windows

I am trying to create a WPF based application which will allows users to edit photos and provide features like:

1. Increase/Decrease Brightness
2. Crop
3. Retro looks
   and lot more.

I am also looking forward to provide more fancy features like : Framing an image, print to a Tshirt, but these are low on priority.

Any open source libraries for that?

P.S -> This is a POC project, even if i miss some features it will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [`BitmapEffects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx) available in WPF, the `BitmapEffects` make use [Shading language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading_language); at present very few effects available in .net Fx. But it is quite easy create your own shaders to adjust the birghtness, gamma, colour saturation, and they can be data bound too. *The great thing about shaders is you apply them to videos as well.*

[Shazzam Tool](http://shazzam-tool.com/) is on of the best tool to create shadders, it lets you try the effect on your images and generate the `C#` or `VB.Net` binding code to use in WPF/Silverlight.

I guess you have to write code to do the image cropping, or quick Google search would help.

Opensource shader effects available here in [codeplex](http://fx.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For a low-level library that allows GDI like operations on bitmaps please see the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library. This is open source and as a disclaimer, I have made a minor contribution to it.

WriteableBitmapEx has functions for drawing shapes, lines, ellipses, applying filters (via matrices, e.g. convolution blur etc), rotation, resize and cropping. You would have to write your own code to apply framing but this could be done by rendering to a separate bitmap and using the Blit function.

Above all its very fast and portable, to WP7 and Silverlight!

Best regards,